# Visibility feature in Foundation in Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, zurb-foundation

Foundation has a feature called [**Visibility**](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/visibility.html) where you just apply a class to an element `show-for-small-only`, `show-for-medium-up`, etc. and the element will show or hide  based on screen size or device orientation. My question is, is there something like this in Boostrap?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities

### Bootstrap 3

**.visible-*xx*** and **.hidden-*xx*** classes ;)

Example: ***.hidden-xs*** to hide only on phone, **.visible-lg** to show only on desktop.

---

### Bootstrap 2

Little bit different on [bootstrap 2](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/scaffolding.html#responsive):

***.hidden-phone** to hide only on phone, **.visible-desktop** to show only on desktop.*

Comment: I gave a shot to Foundation in my last project and it does what is suppose to. The documentation and community SUCK. Boostrap is far SUPERIOR in all ways and works out of the box, not geekiness required. Thanks.

Comment: I never used Foundation, but Boostrap is indeed very well-documented and has a large community. Don't forget to accept the answer if it's quite helpful. ;)